# Problem with tailwind css intellisense in a react typescript app?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I have installed tailwind css and followed the documentation, but the intellisense works in a weird way: if I use tab to autocomplete className, then if my cursor is inside the brackets, the intellisense doesn't work, but once I click off and on again then the intellisense starts working.

I also updated settings.json and added

```
{
  "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
    "typescript": "typescript",
    "javascript": "javascript",
    "html": "HTML"
  }

 "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,

  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "strings": true
  }
```

But nothing seems to help, to use intellisense I first need my caret to go outside of the quotes, and then go back inside.

[Video](https://media.giphy.com/media/5EGcQcuElUh6EeKpz4/giphy.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have where I found solution,
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/392
but if you're too busy to dig in here solution is

```
ctrl + space in quotation marks
```

, it works for me.
I found this question looking for solution and I've found it so here you have.
Have fun c:.